# Is there a way to prevent a side panel in React from re-rendering (scrolling back to the top of the panel) when I click a button on the panel?

Tags: reactjs

In a React app, I have a side panel with multiple accordions, enough that users have to scroll down to see them all.  When I click on a button lower on the panel, the panel appears to re-render (refreshes and looks as if user had scrolled back to the top of the panel).  Is there a way to prevent this re-render so that when a user clicks a button, the panel doesn't move/scroll/re-render (so that the button and accordion that the user was viewing are still visible)?

I expect the panel to not re-render or scroll back to the top when a user clicks a button on the lower part of the panel.

Comment: Would you mind posting the function / state of the parent sidePanel containing your accordion, as well as your accordion component?

Comment: Correction: this was made in MaterialUI, and it's really a list with list items rather than accordions with buttons.  Does that change the situation?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this: it all was related to setState() forcing the sidebar to re-render due to how I handled the keys related to the buttons/tabs in the sidebar.  Since I reset the keys each time a button/tab was clicked, the sidebar re-rendered regardless of the event.preventDefault() I added.  Once I removed the function that reset the keys each time I changed state by clicking a button/tab, the sidebar stopped re-rendering.